# how to hold file input value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

suppose a page contains multi-stage form, in 1st stage of form contains input field for name and in second stage it contains input for file , onChange sets state values for name and file,but when we move back and forth like 1st stage to 2nd stage and sencond stage, we can hold value for input type name but how to hold value for input type file.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pageone: true,
      pagetwo: false,
      pagethree: false,
      pageonedata: "",
      pagetwodata: "",
      pagethreedata: ""
    };
    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
    this.prevPage = this.prevPage.bind(this);
    this.togglePage = this.togglePage.bind(this);
  }

  prevPage() {
    if (this.state.pagetwo === true) {
      this.setState({
        pageone: !this.state.pageone,
        pagetwo: !this.state.pagetwo
      });
    } else if (this.state.pagethree === true) {
      this.setState({
        pagethree: !this.state.pagethree,
        pagetwo: !this.state.pagetwo
      });
    }
  }

  nextPage() {
    if (this.state.pageone === true) {
      this.setState({
        pageone: !this.state.pageone,
        pagetwo: !this.state.pagetwo
      });
    } else if (this.state.pagetwo === true) {
      this.setState({
        pagetwo: !this.state.pagetwo,
        pagethree: !this.state.three
      });
    }
  }

  togglePage() {
    this.setState({
      pageone: !this.state.pageone,
      pagetwo: !this.state.pagetwo
    });
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0] });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ margin: "250px 500px" }}>
        {this.state.pageone && (
          <form>
            <label>
              <h4>page one</h4>
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="pageonedata"
              value={this.state.pageonedata}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </form>
        )}
        {this.state.pagetwo && (
          <form>
            <label>
              <h4>page two</h4>
            </label>
            <input
              type="file"
              name="pagetwodata"
              value={this.state.pagetwodata}
              onChange={this.handleFile}
            />
          </form>
        )}
        {this.state.pagethree && (
          <form>
            <label>
              <h4>page three</h4>
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="pagethreedata"
              value={this.state.pagethreedata}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </form>
        )}
        <br />
        <button
          type="submit"
          onClick={this.prevPage}
          disabled={this.state.pageone ? true : false}
        >
          previous
        </button>{" "}
        <button
          type="submit"
          onClick={this.nextPage}
          disabled={this.state.pagethree ? true : false}
        >
          next
        </button>{" "}
        <button
          type="submit"
          onClick={this.togglePage}
          disabled={this.state.pagethree ? false : true}
        >
          finish
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: your question is about how to hold values from `input` of `type file`?

Comment: yes when we move back and forth of stages i want to hold file input value

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't insert a file into an input element programmatically, only the user can do that, so the best way to keep the file in the input would be to set `display:none;` conditionally on the form instead of removing it from the DOM.

**Example**

```
class App extends Component {
  // ...

  handleFile = e => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0] });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      {/* ... */}
        <form style={{ display: this.state.pagetwo ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
          <label>
            <h4>page two</h4>
          </label>
          <input
            type="file"
            name="pagetwodata"
            value={this.state.pagetwodata}
            onChange={this.handleFile}
          />
        </form>
      {/* ... */}
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks man got the point,i thought we can hold file input value programatically.

Comment: @SrikanthGowda You're welcome! Yeah, it's quite tricky. You can hold the file in state, but it will not be part of the new input element if you remove it and add a new one.

Comment: Thank you,it worked. you catch the point perfectly.best answer

Answer (score 2):

You can now update the input files value using something like this example:

```
const fileInput = document.querySelector(`#your-input-file-id`);
    
const myFile = new File(['Hello World!'], 'myFile.txt', {
   type: 'text/plain',
   lastModified: new Date(),
});

const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
dataTransfer.items.add(myFile);
fileInput.files = dataTransfer.files;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData