# Proper way to change Form.Control text with custom onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I noticed today that while using a custom `onChange` in a `Form.Control` that the text in the field no longer changes when a file is selected. I have looked through the documentation on the Git [HERE](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/form-control/) but it doesnt say how to change the text with a custom event.

my code:

```
    // handles when a file has been selected. 
    const handleUploadChange = (event) =>
    {
        setFileToUpload(event.target.files[0]);
        setIsFilePicked(true);
    }

    // Footer containing buttons and file selection
    const CardFooter = () =>{
        return(
            <Card.Footer>
                <div style={{width:"80%", display : "flex", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center"}}>
                    <div style={{marginRight: "40px"}}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="formFile" className="mb-3">
                            <Form.Control type="file" custom onChange={handleUploadChange} label={fileToUpload === null ? "No File Selected" : fileToUpload.name}/>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </div>
                    <div className="btn-red" style={{marginRight: "40px"}}>
                        <Button disabled={fileToUpload === null} onClick={()=>{setFileToUpload(null); setIsFilePicked(false);}}>Clear</Button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Button disabled={(fileToUpload === null) || (fileToUpload.size >= maxUploadSizeInBytes)} onClick={()=>handleSubmit(fileToUpload)}>Upload</Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Card.Footer>
        )
    }
```

As you can see here, once a file is selected, my change event happens, but the selection box still reads "No file chosen". I have attempted `label`, `text`, `displayName` , and `placeholder` like so: `label={fileToUpload === null ? "No File Selected" : fileToUpload.name}`

[image]

Does anyone know the proper prop to use with a custom onChange ?

Comment: The text shown inside the input, when type="file" is managed automatically and is located. Why do you need a custom text?

Comment: I dont need a custom text, but when I use a custom onChange, the text never changes from "No file chosen" to ""sample.pdf" or whichever file is chosen. The image shows a file is selected by grabbing the data points from it, but the file selector box still shows "No File Chosen" when one actually is selected.

Comment: Can you look into my sandbox? I copy/pasted your code and it works on my side. Where is the difference to yours?

Comment: @IgorGonak I think you linked the wrong sandbox below, it takes to a random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control input of type "file" in React. When you choose a file, the text/"label" should automatically be updated. You don't have to manage it. Just set the state on select and read the state on submission. To fix your clear button, you could use useRef:

```
const fileInputRef = useRef(null);
...
<Form.Control ref={fileInputRef} ...>
...
<Button onClick={() => {
    setFileToUpload(null);
    fileInputRef.current.value = null;
}}>
    Clear
</Button
```

Also consider following:

- You don't need your "isFilePicked" state. It can be derived from "fileToUpload" with `Boolean(fileToUpload)`.
- There is no Form.Control custom property.
- Nore there is a Form.Control label property. If you need a label, add Form.Label to it. You can hide the file input and style your own input solution if you want to.

Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-vaughan-zn68t

Read more:

[how to hold file input value in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51422294/how-to-hold-file-input-value-in-react)

[How to reset ReactJS file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192346/how-to-reset-reactjs-file-input)

Comment: I created a codesandbox with my full page upload code so you can see what I mean, when you select a file and it calls the "onChange event, the name of the file doesnt appear in the box - it will still show "No File Chosen" - https://codesandbox.io/s/form-control-file-upload-pe7kxs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yeah sorry, that's a totally wrong codesandbox. Don't know how it happened. But can't find the right one now.

I have looked into your code and the problem is, that when you set state on change of file input, in rerenders and looses the file selection. I tried to wrap the component with React.memo to prevent rerenders but it didn't worked somehow. If you have your StatusBanner anyway, you can hide the file input and only render a button for example